# How could Dan Briklin's Note Taker draw lines so smoothly?

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I tried to write a similar hand drawing app. But the line drawing is always a little slow.

If you'd written a similar app and got the line drawing optimized, please explain a bit.

[Dan's Note Taker Lite](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/note-taker-lite/id342311693?mt=8).

Answer (score 1):

I would try some of these settings.

Note the bottom setting of AllowAntialiasing.

```
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context,  kCGInterpolationLow);
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, true);
```